# Avoid common prefixes without change lookahead

Tags: javacc

I'm using JavaCC to make a specification to recognize a language. The problem I have is that JavaCC gives me a warning because public is a common prefix of Member() declaration. Member() can has Attributes() and/or Method() but must have at least one Method, the order does not matter.

The warning JavaCC gives me is:

Choice conflict in (...)+ construct at line 66, column 23.
Expansion nested within construct and expansion following construct have common prefixes, one of which is: "public". Consider using a lookahead of 2 or more for nested expansion.

The line 66 is the only line of Member(). Also I need to do this **without change lookahead value**.

Here is the code:

```
void Member() : {}
    {
        (Attribute())* (Method())+ (Attribute() | Method())*
    }

void Attribute() : {}
    {
        "private" Type() <Id> [":=" Expr()]";"
    }

void Method() : {}
    {
        MethodHead() MethodBody()
    }

void MethodHead() : {}
    {
        ("public")? (<Id> | Type() | "void") <Id> "(" Parameter() ")"
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this regular expression

```
 (Method())+ (Attribute() | Method())*
```

is ambiguous.  Let's abbreviate methods by M and attributes by A. If the input is MAM, there no problem. The `(Method())+` matches the first M and the `(Attribute() | Method())*` matches the remaining AM.  But if the input is MMA, where should the divide be?  Either `(Method())+` matches M and `(Attribute() | Method())*` matches MA or `(Method())+` matches MM and `(Attribute() | Method())*` matches A.  Both parses are possible. JavaCC doesn't know which parse you want, so it complains.

What you can do:

- Nothing.  Ignore the warning. The default behaviour is that as many Methods as possible will be recognized by `(Method())+` and only methods after the first attribute will be recognized by `(Attribute() | Method())*`.
- Suppress the warning using lookahead.  You said you don't want to add lookahead, but for completeness, I'll mention that you could change `(Method())+` to `(LOOKAHEAD(1) Method())+`. That won't change the behaviour of the parser, but it will suppress the warning.
- Rewrite the grammar.

The offending line could be rewritten as either

```
(Attribute())* Method() (Attribute() | Method())*
```

or as

```
(Attribute())* (Method())+ [Attribute() (Attribute() | Method())*]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked removing the '+' from Method(). Thanks a lot.